# View error in Flask when retrieving item in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to populate a page built in Flask from items in MongoDB. My route looks like:

```
@app.route('/job/<posting>', methods=["GET"])
def job_post(posting):
    posting = db.openings.find({'Id': posting})
    title = db.openings.find_one({'Id': posting}, {'Title': 1, '_id':0})
    return render_template('post_page.html', posting=posting, title=title)
```

My template page for post_page.html is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content%}

<div class="container">


  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <h3><a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ title }}</a></h3>
    </div> -->
  </article>


</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

When I attempt to access a page, I get an error saying `"bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10dd402e8>, of type: <class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>"`

When I research that error, most of the issues have come from using `find` instead of `find_one`. I am using `find_one` here, and when I test it in a Python shell, the variable type for title is a dictionary, so I'm confused as to why it's passing a cursor object to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `posting` in to the function and then immediately setting it in the first function `posting = db.openings.find({'Id': posting})`. I suspect you don't mean to do this.

`find()` return a cursor which you're then passing into the `find_one()` function which is causing the error you see.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve by calling `find()` then `find_one()` on the same collection. My suggestion is you remove the line `posting = db.openings.find({'Id': posting})`

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: I need to create pages dynamically that have a URL based on the field 'Id' in Mongo. This is a field I created, not the Mongo _id. From there, I need to search Mongo for that Id, pull the value from the Title field, and pass it to the template. I thought I needed to set it right away in order for the URL to be created. I guess that's not the case?

Comment: What do you mean by "set it right away". DId you try my sugestion?

Comment: It did! Thank you so much for the help.